# Create Kindle dictionary as KF8 / Floating images in a Kindle dictionary

Tags: kindle, mobi, image, dictionaries, kf8

I'm working on a [Game of Thrones Kindle dictionary](http://wjdp.github.io/gotdict/) and would like to float images in some of the definitions. (width 20%, floated right)

This is supported on newer kindles using the KF8 format however kindlegen suppresses KF8 support when an index is detected:

```
*************************************************************
 Amazon kindlegen(Linux) V2.9 build 1028-0897292 
 A command line e-book compiler 
 Copyright Amazon.com and its Affiliates 2014 
*************************************************************

Info:I9007:option: -c2: Kindle Huffdic compression
Info:I9014:option: -verbose: Verbose output
Info:I9018:option: -donotaddsource: Source files will not be added
Info(prcgen):I1047: Added metadata dc:Title        "GOTDict"
Info(prcgen):I1047: Added metadata dc:Date         "2016-01-07"
Info(prcgen):I1047: Added metadata dc:Creator      "Various"
Info(prcgen):I1047: Added metadata dc:Description  "Kindle dictionary for A Song of Ice and Fire."
Info(prcgen):I1002: Parsing files  0000005
Info(prcgen):I1003: Parsing file     URL: title.html
Info(prcgen):I1003: Parsing file     URL: toc.html
Info(prcgen):I1003: Parsing file     URL: defs.html
Warning(parser8):W26001: Index not supported for enhanced mobi.
Info(prcgen):I1003: Parsing file     URL: contributing.html
Info(parser8):I12001: Enhanced mobi generation suppressed.
Info(prcgen):I1036: Mobi file built successfully
cp _output/gotdict.mobi _output/site/gotdict.mobi
```

Is there a way to force KF8 output, or to float images in MOBI7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to force KF8 output, or to float images in MOBI7?

Unfortunately, you can't generate KF8 dictionaries and it's unlikely that this situation will change anytime soon, because Amazon inherited the code from Mobipocket and has only implemented cosmetic changes so far:

Note the following KindleGen message:

```
Info(parser8):I12001: Enhanced mobi generation suppressed.
```

That's KindlGen's way of telling you **no KF8 files**.

Comment: Just had a reply from KDP support with this same question, the response was the same. Was really hoping they'd be a work around, either way it's rather infuriating they haven't added dictionary support!

Answer (score 0):

Given the heavy restrictions on block formatting in Mobi 7 this seems to be the best solution for my situation.

Have the images small enough and inline, set the `width` `height` and `align` attributes of the image (and felt very dirty) then place image at the start of a line – title here.

```
<img src="images/house-redfort.png" width="51" height="56" align="middle" >
```

[image: kindle preview screenshot]